# Как подписать apk через консоль?

Tags: android

Есть не подписанный не сделанный в eclipse 1.apk и есть готовый key.keystore .  Надо как  то через **консоль** подписать этим ключом 1.apk. Как (какой командой)?

p.s. Так и не сумел нагуглить. Найдёте подходящий гугло-запрос, напишите плиз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

После этого надо будет еще "выровнять" файл (align, не знаю общепринятого перевода).
Подробная пошаговая инструкция есть на [d.android.com](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp)

Answer (score 1):

даже гуглить ничего не надо, [Святая Святых](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp) всё знает!